# Integrate image with css in div using resolution in percentual

Tags: css, image

I have a div that have `css: height:50%;` and inside there is another div with css: `height:50%;`.
Inside the second `div`, there is an `image`.

I can't have the image in the same dimension respect to height of the two (equal) `div`. 
How can I fix it?

Example:

```
#div1{
height:50%;
position:fixed;
top:25%;
}

#div2{
height:50%;
position:fixed;
top:25%;
}

#image{
height:50%;
position:fixed;
top:25%;
}

<div id="div1">
<div id="div2">
<asp:Image id="image" url=".." runat="server">
</div>
</div>
```

The image is 20x387. The resolution is 1280x1024.

Comment: I set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njUKP/) with your code (just replaced the image). As you can see, all 3 elements do overlap as their position is exactly the same and due to `position:fixed`. Is that really what you wanted? And if so, you do not need any of the DIV elements, as they are empty. So your current markup does not make any sense to me. I also do not fully understand what you want to achieve with the image? And do you really want a layout which is fixed to the one resolution!?

Comment: Yes it's exactly what i want. Three elements overlapped. the first div contain second div that have two images: the first is at the beginning of the div and it's fine. The second image is transparent on the top (because of that, I don't care if they are overlapped) and there are some color on the bottom.  I want this image on the bottom of the div. The point is that: if change resolution I want the image always near the bottom of the div.

Comment: I mean, if I change resolution and the divs are always the same, I want also the image in that way!I don't know if I'm clear enough, please ask me if something is not!

Comment: So the code you posted does not show what you want to achieve in the end. Please provide us with a JSFiddle that contains all things including the images! And how about the rest of the site? Fixed elements are no longer in the "normal flow". And should they be 100% width? I still did not fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but I am very sure that there might be a better approach than the one with `position:fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove position fixed from img element, because position:fixed has no connection with the parent element.

So if you put position fixed to an element, it won't consider what his parent is doing.

Position fixed to that img element is also useless, because it is wrapped by a fixed position element.

Cheers :)